# Adding Previous rows of a dataframe for specific word found in a Dictonary

Tags: python, list, pandas, dictionary

I have a dataframe Which looks like  I have 2 columns here

```
Automated test case name               TC Type  
     name 1                            Pre-Req   
     name 2                            Pre-Req   
     name 3                            Pre-Req   
     name 4                            Pre-Req   
     name 5                            Actual   
     name 6                            Actual   
     name 7                            Pre-Req   
     name 8                            Actual
```

What I have to do is if "Actual" word is found in the column TC Type,
then add the previous all "pre-req"  with all actuals , 
if i found Actuals consecutively i need to take all the pre-Req
before the two "actual" I find I have written the code , but this is not giving me exact result.

Following is my code

```
new_list =[]
prev_list = []
df = data_TC1
Dict_TestCase_Mapping ={}
is_ActualFound = False
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if "Actual" == df['TC Type'][i]:
        Dict_TestCase_Mapping[df['Automated test case name'][i]]= [i,new_list]
        is_ActualFound = True
    else:
        new_list.append(df['Automated test case name'][i])
```

Expected output is

```
 { name 5 :
 [4,
    [name1,
     name2,
     name3,
     name4
   ]]
  name 6 :
  [5,
  [name 1,
   name 2,
   name 3,
   name 4
   ]]
  name 8 :
  [7,
  [name 7
  ]]
```

How do i get this expected output? how to handle if two actuals comes consecuively?

Comment: Please also include current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not utilizing `is_ActualFound` variable as you should. Include this `elif` block in your loop and it should do the work. Please comment below if you don't understand anything. Also let know if it works for you.

```
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if "Actual" == df['TC Type'][i]:
        Dict_TestCase_Mapping[df['Automated test case name'][i]]= [i,new_list]
        is_ActualFound = True
    elif is_ActualFound and df['TC Type'][i] != "Actual":
        new_list = []
        mew_list.append(df['Automated test case name'][i])
        is_ActualFound = False
    else:
        new_list.append(df['Automated test case name'][i])
```

Comment: what if i had to add a new key which will be nested key means i want to add module names column as the 1st key for all the keys and values inside how can we do this?